# Python: appending same string to list by n times

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have given csv file which I divided into rows with semicolons. Each row has a place, product name and amount. It was pretty easy to add each product to list if the amount was 1. But when the amount is >1, then comes the problem.
Dictionary is for counting how many times the item is given in the list. For example:

I have a row where: `Test; Chicken bowl; 4;`

name = `Test`, item = `chicken bowl`, amount = `4`

```
if name =='Test':
    if amount == 1:
       count_test += 1
       test_items.append(item)
    else:
       count_test += 1
       test_items.append(int(amount) * item)
       #listt = [item] * int(amount)
       #test_items.append(listt) 
       print(f'Test checked and count {count_test}')
       print(f'\t {item}; {amount}; ')
```

```
items_dict = {x:test_items.count(x) for x in test_items}
    print(f'Test: {items_dict}')
```

The desired result should be:

- I have list:

```
['FIT salmon bowl 375 kcal', 'Sushi Rice', 'Extra avocado', 'Chicken bowl', 
'Sushi Rice', 'Extra coriander', 'Extra avocado', 'Chicken bowl',
'Chicken bowl','Chicken bowl','Chicken bowl','Chicken bowl', 'Sushi Rice',
 'Salmon bowl','Salmon bowl' 'Sushi Rice', 'Salmon bowl',
'Salmon bowl', 'Quinoa', 'FIT salmon bowl 375 kcal', 'Quinoa']
```

- To dictionary to get the count of each key:

```
Test: {'FIT salmon bowl 375 kcal': 2,
 'Sushi Rice': 4, 'Extra avocado': 2, 'Extra coriander': 1, 
'Chicken bowl': 5, 'Salmon bowl': 4, 'Quinoa': 2}
```

But not like this which I have at the moment:

- List:

```
['FIT salmon bowl 375 kcal', 'Sushi Rice', 'Extra avocado', 'Chicken bowl',
 'Sushi Rice', 'Extra coriander', 'Extra avocado', 
'Chicken bowlChicken bowlChicken bowlChicken bowl', 'Sushi Rice',
 'Salmon bowlSalmon bowl', 'Sushi Rice', 'Salmon bowlSalmon bowl', 
'Quinoa', 'FIT salmon bowl 375 kcal', 'Quinoa']
```

- To dictionary:

```
Test: {'FIT salmon bowl 375 kcal': 2, 'Sushi Rice': 4, 'Extra avocado': 2,
 'Chicken bowl': 1, 'Extra coriander': 1, 
'Chicken bowlChicken bowlChicken bowlChicken bowl': 1, 
'Salmon bowlSalmon bowl': 2, 'Quinoa': 2}
```

Comment: You can pass your list to `collections.Counter` which does exactly this.

Comment: @CoryKramer yes, but my problem right now is that if I have a string which amount is for example 4, I want to append it 4 times in a list not like 'test1test1test1test1', but 'test1, test1, test1, test1' :)

Comment: Oh, so you want to go backwards, in other words from a dict to a list?

Comment: do not you want to use 'item' as a list [item] in this row  
test_items += int(amount) * [item]

Comment: @CoryKramer not exaclty, more like get rows from csv file, add items to list according to the amount and then with dictionary count multiple items in list as it would be {test1 : 4} not {test1test1test1test1 : 1 }

Comment: @StepanKruglov it will give me nested lists for example [['FIT salmon bowl 375 kcal'], ['Sushi Rice'], ['Extra avocado'], ['Chicken bowl'], ['Sushi Rice'], ['Extra coriander'], ['Extra avocado'], ['Chicken bowl', 'Chicken bowl', 'Chicken bowl', 'Chicken bowl'], ['Sushi Rice'], ['Salmon bowl', 'Salmon bowl'], ['Sushi Rice'], ['Salmon bowl', 'Salmon bowl'], ['Quinoa'], ['FIT salmon bowl 375 kcal'], ['Quinoa']] and then how am I able to count items from those :D

Comment: @ChloeJ7 it will not, if you change 
test_items.append(int(amount) * item) 
to 
test_items += int(amount) * [item]

Comment: @StepanKruglov yes sorry, I missed the += sign, seems okay, but now I cannot use this kind of dictionary since it's saying  "unhashable type: 'list' "

Comment: @ChloeJ7 Where does it say 'unhashable type: 'list' '?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227154/discussion-between-stepan-kruglov-and-chloej7).